# Different cut method python 2.6 to 2.7

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I've a very strange problem...
I would to cut off the first part of an string that incoming with number:
es.

> 001 abcdef 001
>
> 002 xyz bla 02a

to:

> abcdef 001
>
> xyz bla 02a

i use this method:

```
self.mystring = str(gData.get())[str(gData.get().find(" ")+1:]
```

In python 2.7 with this method works:

> abcdef 001
>
> xyz bla 02a

but in python 2.6 this method give me this result:

> 001
>
> bla 02a

how i can resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: What is the `gData`?  Put `print repr(gData.get())` in the method, and check what it print.

Comment: its a inherited method, i need to know if exist another method to cut off first number in string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method:

```
>>> '001 abcdef 001'.split(None, 1)   # `1` to split at most once
['001', 'abcdef 001']
>>> '001 abcdef 001'.split(None, 1)[1]
'abcdef 001'
```

(used `None` to split by any consecutive whitespace)

The possible cause of the second result in the question is that you cut the already-cut string. (not because of difference between Python 2.6 and Python 2.7)

```
>>> '001 abcdef 001'.split(None, 1)[1]
'abcdef 001'
>>> 'abcdef 001'.split(None, 1)[1]
'001'
```